# How to sum time string in an array?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Suppose, I've an array of different time string.

```
let a: any = ["7:20", "5:50", "6:30"];
```

I want to sum up these HH:mm time strings. I am building up an app using Ionic 4 (Angular). I have already used momentjs for these. But, unfortunately yet I can't find any solution.

*Update:*
**Expected Result:**
7:20 + 5:50 + 6:30 = 19:40 (HH:33)

Comment: what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: what result you want exactly ?

Comment: @Praveen I am expecting, Total Hour: 19:40 (HH:mm)

Comment: Why shouldn't `moment("7:20", "H:mm")` not work?

Comment: @sunielkalwani 7:20 + 5:50 + 6:30 = 19:40 (Total Hours)

Comment: @Oliver I can format the time string. But, can't sum up all the times together which I have to get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can treat time as [moment durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) that can be summed up:

```js
const any = ['7:20', '7:52', '5:03', '1:01', '9:02', '6:00'];

const sum = any.reduce((acc, time) => acc.add(moment.duration(time)), moment.duration());

console.log([Math.floor(sum.asHours()), sum.minutes()].join(':'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting correct result from  console.log(sum.asHours()); But when I convert Hours to HH:mm the result is not expected! 
My Sample Input time: 7:20 + 7:52 + 5:03 + 1:01 + 9:02 + 6:00 = 36:18. But it shows 12:18 which is wrong.

Comment: Can you please specify how do you perform conversion from a duration to 'HH:mm' 
 format? Did you try to approach from the updated answer (that implies getting hours and minutes separately and joining them afterwards)?

Comment: Yes, I am just using your updated code. Can you plz check it using my above comment sample inputs? I think you can understand.

Comment: @AbhijitM.Abhi Sorry for the confusion, I got your point and updated the answer that uses absolute number of hours, please take a look.

Comment: Exactly the correct answer what I am expecting that you have done with a few lines of code. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `reduce` method by passing a *callback* function.

```js
let arr= ["7:20", "5:50", "6:30"];
toSeconds = (str) => {
   str = str.split(':');
   return (+str[0]) * 60 + (+str[1]);  
}

toHHss = (seconds) => {
   let minutes = parseInt(seconds/60);
   seconds = seconds - minutes*60;
   return minutes + ':' + seconds;
}
let result = arr.reduce((r,elem) => r + toSeconds(elem), 0);
console.log(toHHss(result));
```

Comment: The *toHHss* function doesn't format the minutes correctly, it produces H:m whereas the OP seems to want H:mm. The *seconds* parameter should probably be named *minutes*. :-)

Comment: @RobG, `result` will hold the total number of seconds after we do sum. Then I just convert the seconds to HH:MM format

Answer (score 3):

A POJS solution can be very simple:

```js
/* Add array of time strings in H:mm format
** @param {Array<string>} timeArray - Array of H:mm
** @returns {string} - sum of times in H:mm format
*/
function addTimes(timeArray) {
  let mins = timeArray.reduce((acc, time) => {
    let [h, m] = time.split(':');
    acc += h*60 + m*1;
    return acc;
  }, 0);
  return (mins/60|0) + ':' + ('0'+(mins%60)).slice(-2);
}

// Example
console.log(addTimes(["7:20", "5:03", "6:42"]));
```

Comment: Compliments on a nice and concise answer. Great testament to using functional programming paradigms too. AND NO GIGANTIC LIBRARY NEEDED

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla Javascript implementation:

```js
const secondsToHm = s => ({
  hours: ((s - s % 3600) / 3600) % 60, 
  minutes: ((s - s % 60) / 60) % 60, 
})

let a = ["7:20", "5:50", "6:30"];
let total = 0; 

for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  const aSlice = a[i].split(':');
  const aSeconds = (+aSlice[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+aSlice[1]) * 60;
  total += aSeconds
}

console.log(`${secondsToHm(total).hours}:${secondsToHm(total).minutes}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.duration() to get the number of milliseconds for each time string in the array, and add them.

```
a.reduce((acc, t) => acc.add(moment.duration(t)), moment.duration())
```